# Why does git need to remove duplicate objects when merging branches?

Tags: version-control, git

Git displayed "removing duplicate objects" after I merged a branch to another and noticed my .git/objects folder has significantly reduced (from 40.7 MB to 33.5 MB).

Isn't branch just supposed to be a pointer, so why git needs to delete some objects?

What actually happened there?

Is it simply git's natural behavior?

Comment: I'm not sure but this sounds like the "garbage collection" it does periodically, which can be invoked manually with `git gc`.

Answer (score 3):

During garbage collection, git takes the objects from your `.git/objects` directory, and *packs* them into the *packfile* in `.git/objects/pack`. During this phase, it also compresses the files and takes advantage of the similarity between files to reduce their size. Typically the *packfile* will increase in size a lot less than the size of the *objects* that have been moved into it, as it is able to do inter-file optimisations.

Once these *objects* are in the *packfile* then there these *objects* are actually in your local repository twice, once as an *object* file, and once in the *packfile*. The "removing duplicate objects" phase, then removes these duplicates from your `.git/objects` directory, and so the size of the directory is decreased.